# Alert javascript function not allowing me to place multiplication in the same place as text

Tags: javascript

I am working on a button in javascript that prompts someone for a MPH number and multiplies it by 1.46667 to get the feet per second. The button works without the text written but when i add text it stops working. The code i have that works is this:

```
function persecond(){
var number = prompt("MPH")
alert(number*1.46667)
}
```

When i try to change the code to this

```
function persecond(){
var number = prompt("MPH")
alert("You would be traveling" number*1.46667 "feet per second.")
}
```

It does not work. Am i making a simple mistake that can be easily fixed or is it a bit more complicated then that?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/String_Operators

Answer (score 0):

```
function persecond(){
var number = prompt("MPH")
alert("You would be traveling "+ number*1.46667 +" feet per second.")
}
```

Comment: Glad to know that, you make it work. Please don't forget to mark this as an Answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the string `number` into a integer. You can use `parseInt()` like so:

```
parseInt("5"); //5
```

---

Plus you need to concatenate your number and string, like so:

```
function persecond(){
    var number = prompt("MPH")

    number = parseInt(number) //string to int        

    alert("You would be traveling" + number*1.46667 + "feet per second.")
}
```

---

Reference:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Comment: The multiplication operator implicitly converts its operands to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the concat in your alert, example:

```
    alert('You would be traveling'+ number*1.46667 + 'feet per second.');
```

Hope that helps

Best regards!

Comment: Glad to know that my friend, (y)

Answer (score 0):

this should Work:

```
function persecond(){
   var number = prompt("MPH")
   alert("You would be traveling" + number*1.46667 + "feet per second.")
}
```

you can always use parseInt the prompt return but I doubt there will be a need since it will try to parse it when you multiply by 1.46667